# Aggregate rows based on MIN flag

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm thinking this is an easy one but the answer is escaping me.

Example: I have a query returning 10 rows, some of which are identical except for the last 2 columns which are a **comment** and a number(**language-flag**). I would like to know how to always return the row with the lowest language-flag number for each of these semi identical rows.

I've been assuming the idea would be to MIN(language-flag), however the grouping process this requires makes the query still return 2 rows as the comments contents are different.

An example image i created is here:

[image: Example]

Any help is appreciated.

Follow up question:

In the confusion I had forgotten why I originally needed to ask this question.

If the comments field happens to be null, when there is the same COL2 with a higher lang-flag, then that should be the selected row, if there is no higher lang-flag row and the comments field is null then just the null comments row should be selected.

I've created another example image for this case:

[image]

Comment: what is the logic of ROW2 in output

Comment: My example image was wrong, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can also use `group by`:

```
select min(comments) keep (dense_rank first order by lang_flag) as comments,
       col1, col2,
       min(lang_flag) as lang_flag
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

If you have a large amount of data, it might be interesting to see which of the three suggested methods are fastest.

Comment: I'll give all 3 a go and let you know. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rank()` to rank records by `lang_flag` within groups of records having the same `(col1, col2)`, and then filter out on the top record per group:

```
select col1, col2, comments, lang_flag
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by col1, col2 order by lang_flag) rn
    from mytable t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi, I've added a follow up question, would you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

use corelated subquery

```
select a.* from table_name a
where a.lang_flag=(select min(lang_flag) from table_name b 
                          where a.comments=b.comments and a.col2=b.col2)
```

Comment: Hi, I've added a follow up question, would you take a look?

Comment: @LiamMorgan, why don't you add it in the same question?

Comment: I've edited my original question if that's what you mean